FedEx API Rate Quote Returns 404: "The resource you requested is no longer available"
I'm trying to integrate the FedEx API to get shipping rate quotes in my Node.js application. I've followed the documentation, but I'm consistently getting a 404 error with the message:

"The resource you requested is no longer available."

FedEx API request failed with status: 404
- Response body: {"transactionId": "c2dda9ea-61fa-411a-9e39-e70239ee9370","errors":[{"code":"NOT.FOUND.ERROR","message":"The resource you requested is no longer available. Please modify your request and try again."}]}

I have verified the endpoint URL and the request payload based on the FedEx API documentation. Here is the relevant part of my index.js:
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());

const FEDEX_OAUTH_URL = 'https://apis.fedex.com/oauth/token';
const FEDEX_API_URL = 'https://apis.fedex.com/rate/v1/rates/quote';
const FEDEX_API_KEY = 'your_api_key';
const FEDEX_SECRET = 'your_api_secret';
const FEDEX_ACCOUNT_NUMBER = 'your_account_number';

async function getFedexToken() {
  const response = await fetch(FEDEX_OAUTH_URL, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },
    body: new URLSearchParams({
      grant_type: 'client_credentials',
      client_id: FEDEX_API_KEY,
      client_secret: FEDEX_SECRET
    })
  });

  const responseBody = await response.text();
  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error(`Failed to get FedEx OAuth token: ${response.statusText}. Response Body: ${responseBody}`);
  }

  const data = JSON.parse(responseBody);
  return data.access_token;
}

app.post('/compare', async (req, res) => {
  const { originPostcode, originCountry, destinationPostcode, destinationCountry, weight } = req.body;

  const fedexRequest = {
    accountNumber: {
      value: FEDEX_ACCOUNT_NUMBER
    },
    requestedShipment: {
      shipper: {
        address: {
          postalCode: originPostcode,
          countryCode: originCountry.toUpperCase()
        }
      },
      recipient: {
        address: {
          postalCode: destinationPostcode,
          countryCode: destinationCountry.toUpperCase()
        }
      },
      shipDateStamp: new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0], // Today's date in YYYY-MM-DD format
      pickupType: 'DROPOFF_AT_FEDEX_LOCATION',
      serviceType: 'INTERNATIONAL_PRIORITY',
      rateRequestType: ['LIST', 'ACCOUNT'],
      customsClearanceDetail: {
        dutiesPayment: {
          paymentType: 'SENDER',
          payor: {
            responsibleParty: null
          }
        },
        commodities: [
          {
            description: 'Camera',
            quantity: 1,
            quantityUnits: 'PCS',
            weight: {
              units: 'KG',
              value: weight
            },
            customsValue: {
              amount: 100,
              currency: 'USD'
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      requestedPackageLineItems: [
        {
          weight: {
            units: 'KG',
            value: weight
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  };

  console.log('FedEx Request Payload:', JSON.stringify(fedexRequest, null, 2));

  try {
    const token = await getFedexToken();
    const response = await fetch(FEDEX_API_URL, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'X-locale': 'en_US',
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(fedexRequest)
    });

    const responseBody = await response.text();
    if (!response.ok) {
      console.error('FedEx API request failed with status:', response.status);
      console.error('Response body:', responseBody); // Log the detailed error response
      throw new Error(`FedEx API request failed with status ${response.status}: ${responseBody}`);
    }

    const fedexData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
    console.log('FedEx Response Data:', JSON.stringify(fedexData, null, 2));

    if (!fedexData.output || !fedexData.output.rateReplyDetails) {
      throw new Error(`Unexpected FedEx API response structure: ${JSON.stringify(fedexData)}`);
    }

    const results = fedexData.output.rateReplyDetails.map(detail => ({
      courier: 'FedEx',
      cost: detail.ratedShipmentDetails[0].totalNetChargeWithDutiesAndTaxes.amount,
      service: detail.serviceType,
      transitTime: detail.commitDetails[0].commitTimestamp
    }));

    res.json({ results });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching data from FedEx API:', error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: error.message });
  }
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'));
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
}).on('error', (err) => {
  if (err.code === 'EADDRINUSE') {
    console.error(`Port ${PORT} is already in use.`);
  } else {
    console.error(err);
  }
});


I was expecting to receive a rate quote from FedEx for the shipment details provided, but instead, I keep receiving a 404 error. I have validated the endpoint and the request payload structure, but I am unsure what is causing the resource to be "no longer available."
Questions:

Is the endpoint URL correct for obtaining rate quotes?
Does the payload structure meet the FedEx API requirements?
Are there any additional headers or parameters required that I might be missing?


I think they might just be sending 404 because you don't have an API, secrect, or account number. Or maybe you are just hiding those things from this post? (which would make sense). From what I can see your code looks good and your following the docs correctly but they might just not being finding that order.

You miss an s at the end of your endpoint after quote. Full URL is https://apis.fedex.com/rate/v1/rates/quotes and not https://apis.fedex.com/rate/v1/rates/quote
Edit :
If that still doesn't work, base URL might actually be https://developer.fedex.com/api/en-fr/catalog/rate/v1/rate/v1/rates/quotes as we can see in the
documentation console. This seems a bit weird to me though and I think there is a double /rate/v1 that shouldn't be there.

Thank you, that fixed the issue. I was missing the “s”
